# Passing numpy ndarray as keras input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset that consists of numpy array and I need to pass this data as input for keras.

| Idx | Target | RF | DL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | P219109 | [0.05555555555555555, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,... | [1.1074159, -5.242936, -6.9121795, 0.931392, -... |
| 1 | P219109 | [0.5833333333333334, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... | [-9.173296, -4.847732, -2.5727227, 8.794523, 7... |
| 2 | P219109 | [0.05555555555555555, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,... | [2.5204952, 1.3955389, -4.755222, -1.7222288, ... |
| 3 | P219109 | [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... | [1.4951401, 1.2499368, -3.08991, -2.0176327, -... |
| 4 | P219109 | [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... | [-3.4984744, 7.1746902, -0.36313212, -3.760725... |

And here my code:

```
X = df[['RF', 'DL']]
y = df['Target']
_, y_ = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
y = y_
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=42)
train_labels = to_categorical(y_train)
test_labels = to_categorical(y_test)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(40, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=36)
```

And I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/FINAL/main.py", line 81, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=40)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1050, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1100, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 263, in __init__
    x, y, sample_weights = _process_tensorlike((x, y, sample_weights))
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1016, in _process_tensorlike
    inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_numpy_and_scipy, inputs)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 659, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 659, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1011, in _convert_numpy_and_scipy
    return ops.convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(x, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1404, 
in convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1410, 
in convert_to_tensor_v2
    return convert_to_tensor(
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py", line 163, 
in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1540, 
in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 264, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 276, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 301, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\ni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Keras: 2.4.0
Tensorflow: 2.4.0
Python: 3.8

**EDIT:**
How to pass a data frame object as a NumPy array? The RF column and DL column are the results of predict_proba from two different models. So, I joined it into a pandas data frame using the following code:

```
rf = [item for item in rf1]
dl = [item for item in out]
y = y_test
df = pd.Series(rf)
df = df.to_frame()
df.rename(columns = {0:'RF'}, inplace = True)
df['Target'] = y
df['DL'] = dl
cols = ['Target', 'RF', 'DL']
df = df[cols]
```

I also tried this:

```
X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)
```

but it doesn't work as I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: `X_train` needs to be a numeric dtype array (ie. all floats).  Your `X` is a dataframe with object dtype columns, ones that contain lists.  The fix is to rework `X` into a proper numeric array.

Comment: you can try:

`X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)`

Comment: What kind of input does your model accept (as `X_train`).  What dtype and what shape? WIthout a clear idea of that, you can't create an appropriate array.  Combining the `rf1` and `out` via a dataframe probably isn't helping you.  Build the array directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it would be best if you created your arrays directly instead of having a DataFrame in the middle.

The problem is that even if `X` is a numpy array, it contains other arrays because Pandas returns an array for each row and each cell. An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'RF':[np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), np.array([6, 2, 3, 4, 5])], 'DL': [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), np.array([7, 2, 3, 4, 5])]})

print(df)
```

```
                RF               DL
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  [6, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [7, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
X = df[['RF', 'DL']].to_numpy()

print(X)
```

```
[[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
 [array([6, 2, 3, 4, 5]) array([7, 2, 3, 4, 5])]]
```

You can reshape to try to fix the problem. This should work:

```
# You have to reshape each cell in each row.
X = np.array([np.reshape(x, (1, len(X[0][0]))) 
              for i in range(len(X)) 
              for x in X[i]]).reshape(-1, 2*len(X[0][0])).astype(np.float32)

print(X)
print(X.shape)
```

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 2. 3. 4. 5. 7. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]
(2, 10)
```

Obviously, this assumes the shapes of the arrays in both the `'RF'` and `'DL'` columns are the same, which I believe is true because they are the output of `predict_proba`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot! Can I simplify it by skip creating data frame and create X with `X = np.concatenate((rf, out), axis=-1)` ?

Comment: @fairy yes, exactly. Skipping the dataframe would be the best option. What you wrote should work. Here I tried to explain what goes wrong with the df in the middle